# Реализация Singleton в С++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton

Функция, которая возвращает `singleton`:

```
static SingletonDatabase& get()
{
    static SingletonDatabase db;
    return db;
}
```

Это новый способ реализации этого паттерна вместо того, что бы создавать приватное поле `static Singleton* instance`, а потом отдельно функцию, которая его возвращает.

Не могу понять, как вообще это работает и что это значит? Локальное статическое поле, с конструктором по умолчанию.

Почему эта реализация лучше предыдущих?

Comment: Потому что вам не нужно проверять пуст ли указатель на интсанс.

Comment: Интересно, почему "*новый*"? Или просто новое - это очень хорошо забытое старое?..

Comment: Не самое лучшее определять статик внутри статика.. имхо конечно

Comment: @NewView и в чём минусы статика внутри статика ?

Comment: @ampawd, по аналогии с `C` в способе выделения памяти, и хранения переменной, обычно к таким конструкциям внутри приделывали `volatile` чтоб компилятор ее не 'унес'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Этот способ не нов, просто раньше (до C++11) он не был потокобезопасен. Чем эта реализация лучше предыдущих? Тем, что не требует явного создания мьютекса для многопоточного использования, при этом занимает всего 2 строчки. Это простейший `Singleton`, который выполняет свою задачу. Что ещё нужно?

Что касается того, как это работает: статическая переменная (не важно локальная она или нет) создается один раз. Локальная создаётся в момент первого вызова функции и живёт до конца работы программы. Т.е. можно считать, что первая строчка функции выполняется всего один раз, когда впервые вызвана, а во всех остальных случаях просто происходит возврат ссылки.

Comment: Интересно, что же такое было до С++11, что метод, возвращающий адрес очевидно размещенной в .bss и инициализируемой по умолчанию 0-м (memset из Crt1.s) статической переменной, которая  одна для всех потоков, не является потокобезопасным?

Comment: @avp, адрес не причём, там вообще-то объект конструируется в первой строчке. А это, в общем случае, нетривиальная операция.

Comment: Точно, не обратил внимания на *многобукв*, в самом деле (все же дурацкий язык), тогда конструктор будет вызываться при первом обращении (и в этот вызов нужно встраивать mutex)

Comment: @avp, в C++ есть гарантия, что инициализация статической переменной выполняется только один раз и только одним потоком, т.е. реализация обязана гарантировать отсутствие гонок. До C++11 этого не было, т.к. C++ не подозревал о существовании потоков :)